# Facing an issue while rendering PPTs of Powerpoint 2013 through poweroint API in my application

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, powerpoint-2010

I am facing an issue while rendering slides of presentations made in PowerPoint 2013.

**Actual Scenario:**

I have a presentation let's say "test.pptx", just created in PowerPoint 2013 & let's say there are four slides. Now while i am rendering slides in the output window then it moves fine to next slide  while i trigger on the window. However when i click to move to last slide then after showing the last slide it Shows a message that "Do you want to save your presentation or not". And suppose i click on don't save then it hangs.

Just FYI my application running in VS-2010 with wpf.

So please help me out if you have faced this issue earlier or if you have any solution or alternative for this.

Looking for your help!!!
Thanks Guys.

Comment: You'd most likely need to work out what you're doing to change the presentation and stop doing it OR before that dialog comes up, set the presentation's .Saved property to True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't recall the exact details off the top of my head, but I think one of the options on the open dialog is read only.

Marking the active presentation .Saved = True is the real answer to your problem, here is a VB.Net sample using dynamic binding (not the Interop Assemblies):

```
pp = The PowerPoint Application Object

Dim ppa As Object = pp.ActivePresentation
ppa.Saved = True
```